# How to use Java Buildpack in Bluemix Docker?

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud

I am new to Bluemix and docker. I want to use Java buildpack instead of the default IBMLiberty in docker container on Bluemix.
is it possible? I tried searching on internet but could not find relevant information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buildpack and docker (IBM Container) images are two different things.

The IBMLiberty docker/container images has a Liberty runtime deployed on it, but it is not using buildpack technology.

If you don't want to use IBMLiberty container images, you can load docker hub images into your private registry.  The link below contains the information.

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_images_pulling.html

Basically, you load a docker hub image locally and push it to your private registry in Bluemix.  One of the image choice is ubuntu.

https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/

After you loaded the image to your private registry, you can use "cf ic run" to run a container using that image.  Here is the reference,

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_cli_reference_cfic.html#container_cli_reference_cfic__run

Here are more info on using Docker image on Bluemix and cf ic commands,

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_images_adding_ov.html
https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_cli_reference_cfic.html